# Enforce HTTPS on all pages in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got an ASP.NET MVC3 application running on a shared server. I've installed an SSL certificate on the server and all controllers in my application are adorned with RequireHTTPS. The intention was to be sure that no pages are served unencrypted (i.e. all pages are served via HTTPS).

However, CERTAIN pages (e.g. js, an HTML error page) CAN be accessed unencrypted (by adding :80 to the hostname in the request). Granted, the pages I am talking about are static but how can I secure ALL pages in my site, preventing ANY of them being downloaded unencrypted. I don't have access to the IIS server settings as this is a shared site, but is there a way by using an HTTP Handler or Rewrite URL module (or can I set the permissions directly on the file folders)?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: What you mean by pages? html files?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/165835/how-to-restrict-access-to-web-pages-for-https

Comment: Appreciate your response, Mark. By "pages" I meant all of Html pages, JS scripts, image files. I have since deduced the problem for MOST of these (I think): including them using @Url.Content, which has since been replaced with direct "https://..." links. However, I'm using DevExpress components and they have a handler accessed through "DXR.axd" which doesn't use encryption to request resources (e.g. CSS files, images) and I'm not sure if that can be changed. Something is still being accessed insecurely and I'll need to ferret it out or die trying. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use an action filter attribute like this

```
public class RequireSSL : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        //Check if we're secure or not and if we're on the local machine
        if (!req.IsSecureConnection && !req.IsLocal)
        {

            var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url)

                              {
                                  Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
                                  Port = 443
                              };
            res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }


}
```

Then i created a base controller called SecureController with this attribute

```
  [RequireSSL]
 public class SecureController : Controller
{

}
```

then any controller that I want to be SSL will inherit this controller. 
Hope that helps
you will just need to make sure that all 'pages' are views returned by a controller action. This should be a pretty easy change if it is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not an expert and I'd like to learn; what does this ActionFilter do that [RequireHttps] doesn't? Anyway, the issue may be in the way I request content files; I used @Url.Content, I've replaced that every place I can with direct "https://..." links. I then tried only allowing Anonymous Access through SSL and I still am asked to authorize. So there is still SOMETHING being accessed insecurely, I think it may be related to the DevExpress components, they have a handler accessed through "DXR.axd" which does not use encryption and AFAIK can't be changed. I'll keep trying. Thanks again.

Comment: I actually was unaware of the RequireHttps Action Filter :) It may have been released after i created this one.. I created this back in mvc 2 I believe. So yea it does the same thing that the one I created does. Thanks for the info on that.

Comment: You mean I actually made a CONTRIBUTION? :) Hard for me to believe...anyway, I'm going to need to do some serious studying on HTTP, HTTPS, ports 80 and 443, etc. because I really don't know if the @Url.Content is the issue or if it's something else. I mean: adding :80 to the hostname and reissuing a request? Again, thanks for your time.